# HTTP 301 Error - Is it a big deal?

Tags: http, http-status-code-301, google-search-console, http-error

I was testing out a site using Google Webmaster Tools and noticed that almost all the links have been 'redirected'.  I receive an HTTP 301 error / warning stating such.  Is this actually a big deal or is this something that can commonly happen?  Some changes were made to the site recently and I don't know whether this was happening before or not.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future please ask such questions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP 301 is not an error. It is just an indication that the resources you are linking to / pointing to have moved.

Normally your client should follow the redirection.

See more information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Comment: Oh okay, but so if I didn't move them why would they have moved?  It's just a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @MaxPower — Odds are that you entered the wrong URL and the server is smart enough to recognise the "not quite right" URL and redirect to the right one. This is common with missing a `/` from a URL or using mod_spelling.